# Detect switch user with powershell

Tags: powershell, switch-user

I want to register the date and time of each time switch user is invoked in a machine. How can I do that? Something similar to this but for the "switch user" event: [detect log off and on with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172111/detect-logging-off-and-logging-in-powershell)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for this :

```
Event ID 4778 : A user has logged by selecting Switch user command (Fast User Switching).
Event ID 4779 : A user has logged back on using Switch user command (Fast User Switching).
```

But these events appears in "Security" event log only when you configure "Audit conexion events" in the auditing stratégie.

[image]

Sorry for the french screen, but I think that's better than nothing.

After that when using "Fast User Switching", if you filter events IDs 4778 and 4779, you can see something like :

[image]

So the powerShell adaption of the code you point in your question is something like :

```
clear-Host
$UserProperty = @{n="User";e={$_.ReplacementStrings[0]}}
$TypeProperty = @{n="Action";e={switch($_.EventID) {4778 {"SwitchOn"} 4779{"SwitchOff"}}}}
$TimeProeprty = @{n="Time";e={$_.TimeGenerated}}
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -Source Microsoft-Windows-security-auditing | where {$_.EventID -eq 4778 -or $_.EventID -eq 4779} | select $UserProperty,$TypeProperty,$TimeProeprty
```

I hope this helps.

JP

PS : [you can find other informations about "Fast user switching" in french there](http://www.silogix.fr/blog-Silogix/Detection-du-changement-dutilisateur-rapide.aspx).